# how to associate simple product to configurable product magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

I have 6 simple products and 2 that have same attributes( number of page and color ) so when i tried with the geneerate configuration i just have 6 products childs but i can't add the two others so i deleted all the product the i created the child (simple pdoduct) then i tried to associate them manually but i am just able to add 6 and the others product that have same attributes i can't add them is there a way to add from BO a simple product to configurable product not according to configuration and do anyone faced this issue ?? help please

Comment: you can't do this via the BO

Comment: so how to do that please and thanks for your replay